# Is Azure AD App registration required for every customer that uses our application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We have a scenario in which we are trying to integrate Microsoft's Graph API in one of our web applications which will enable our customers to pull their Mail information by clicking one button on the web app. As evident from the docs, one needs to register their app in the Microsoft's Azure Active Directory portal but I'm a little confused about how this will be performed for each customer that uses our web app.

There are two possible ways I think this can be done and I'm confused which route I should take:

1- We use our own Azure AD portal and register the app only there, use its Client ID, Secret etc and then customers can simply sign in to their personal accounts on our web app to use the Graph API on their mailbox

2- We require each customer to register an app in their own Azure portal and give us their Client ID, Secret etc information and then we sign them in to use the Graph API on their mailbox

Please forgive me if I miss anything obvious in the my description as I'm very new to MS Graph API. Let me know which scenario (if it makes sense) should I use to achieve this or any other information that I can provide to help you guide me.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering an app for the purpose to authenticate/authorize users .There will not be any difference if you create multiple apps for the same purpose.

It  is recommended to use First scenario which you have mentioned and does not require creation of Multiple applications,  It is delegated authentication where the users have to log in with his credentials to access his [mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) information  via MS Graph.